# take a picture and save it using android studio

Tags: android, image, save, photo, take

I wrote a program that can take a picture .
The problem is when I try to save it in DIRECTORY_PICTURES I can't find the picture I took in pictures directory what is the wrong with my code the?.
The program I wrote open the camera with no problem and I can take
the picture successfully but there is no image in pictures directory

```
 ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView) ;
}


static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;
public void bucapture(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        try {
            createImageFile();
            galleryAddpic();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

String mCurrentPhotpPath;
//create image name
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName="JPGE"+timeStamp+"_";
    File storgeDir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image=File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storgeDir);
    mCurrentPhotpPath="file:"+image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


//save image
private void galleryAddpic(){
    Intent mediaScanIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f=new File(mCurrentPhotpPath);
    Uri contentUri=Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

  }
}
```

Comment: You never actually output the bitmap to the drive anywhere

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is one of the best can take photo full size in android an save it but create temp file that what exactly is in your code. it doesn't work some of custom phones like some model of samsung & Mi there you can check for file 
//and you have to use Intent Action picker intent for that.

private URI mImageUri;

Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
File photo;
try
{
    // place where to store camera taken picture
    photo = this.createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");
    photo.delete();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Can't create file to take picture!");
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Please check SD card! Image shot is impossible!", 10000);
    return false;
}

mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
//start camera intent
activity.startActivityForResult(this, intent, MenuShootImage);

private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception
{
    File tempDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    tempDir=new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/.temp/");
    if(!tempDir.exists())
    {
        tempDir.mkdirs();
    }
    return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
 }
```

//Then after image capture intent finished to work - just grab your     picture from imageUri using following code:

```
public void grabImage(ImageView imageView)
{
    this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(mImageUri, null);
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try
    {
        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,    mImageUri);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to load", e);
    }
}

//called after camera intent finished taking photo
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   intent)
 {
    if (requestCode==MenuShootImage && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
       ImageView imageView;
       this.grabImage(imageView);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
 }
```